# Trying to find a counter example

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

If $f$ is bounded and continuous on $R^n$ to $R$ and if $f(x_0) >0$.

1) Show that $f$ is strictly positive on some neighborhood of $x_0$.

2) Does the same conclusion hold if $f$ is merely continuous at $x_0$?

---

1) It's pretty simple really. Since $f$ is continuous, then by definition we have that if $V$ is a neighborhood of $f(x_0)$ such that $V = \{y \in R(f) : y > 0 \} $ then there is a corresponding neighborhood $U \subset D(f)$ of $x_0$ such that every elements in $U$ get map inside $V$. Thus $f$ is strictly positive on the neighborhood $U$ of $x$. \

2) This is the part that kinda bother me. It seems like it's true without requiring the fact that the function $f$ to be bounded. But somehow I feel like there is an importance reason why the author put the bounded condition there. **Any advice???**

Comment: What is $R(f)$?

Comment: A function  continuous at one point is locally bounded (bounded in some neighborhood of the point).

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the fact that $f$ is bounded in your answer to $(1)$? No. Therefore it doesn't matter whether $f$ is bounded or not.

Comment: good point! I tried to find a counter example because I was thinking the author has some interesting function in mind... but I just realized that the boundedness was never used in the first part! Thanks!

Comment: @MathStudent You're welcome. Oftentimes authors will play around a bit with assumptions, as a way for the reader to really own a result (get a feeling of what matters).

Answer (score 0):

Although the OP sailed through $\text{(1)}$ with

> $\quad$ "It's pretty simple really."

I am 'bothered' by their definition of $V$ (see Arnaud Mortier's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3413104/trying-to-find-a-counter-example#comment7019464_3413104)).

The $R(f)$ stuff is 'all wet'; here is analysis for $\text{(1)}$ using a fact that the OP might not be aware of, but they can rework their own argument using the definition of continuity at a point.

Proposition: If $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ is a continuous function then
the inverse image of every open interval $(a,b)$ under $f$ is open $\Bbb R^n$.

With $f(x_0) \gt 0$ consider the open interval $I = \big(\frac{f(x_0)}{2}, 2 f(x_0)\big)$. By proposition the set

$\tag 1 U = f^{-1}(I)$

is open and obviously contains $x_0$. So it is a neighborhood of $x_0$.

Of course when we apply $f$ to any point $x \in U$ we get $f(x) \gt \frac{f(x_0)}{2} \gt 0$.

Since proposition 1 is true when $a,b \in \{-\infty,+\infty\}$, we could also use the interval $I = (0,+\infty)$.